# Minimum date of each continuous block of data of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with time-series data as follows:

```
      Date      Value
0  2021-12-01     A
1  2021-12-02     A
2  2021-12-03     A
3  2021-12-04     B
4  2021-12-05     B
5  2021-12-06     A
6  2021-12-07     A
7  2021-12-08     C
```

I'm trying to reduce this to only have the first date of each continuous block for the Value column. So the result would look like:

```
      Date      Value
0  2021-12-01     A
1  2021-12-04     B
2  2021-12-06     A
3  2021-12-08     C
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways of masking, dropping duplicates based on the mask, etc. but cannot do it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ne` (not equals) + `shift`​ to create a mask where the first value of each consecutive group is True, and then `cumsum` to create a unique for each group that's shared by all its items.

Then, `drop_duplicates` based on *that*, and use index of the returned rows to index the dataframe:

```
subset = df.loc[df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift(1)).cumsum().drop_duplicates().index]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
         Date Value
0  2021-12-01     A
3  2021-12-04     B
5  2021-12-06     A
7  2021-12-08     C
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I had the first part (`ne + shift`) and the last part (`drop_duplicates`) but was missing the `cumsum`.

Comment: Yeah, cumsum is useful for WAY more than just getting the cumsum of a numeric column and putting it somewhere... ;)